incorrect cross-reference to an item in an enumerated list with bespoke labels
This posting is inspired by a recent query that asked a related, but not identical, question.
Suppose that one wishes to display the labels of an enumerated list as if they were equation numbers (with the equation numbers placed on the left). In fact, the list items are supposed to share the equation counter. The following MWE accomplishes this with the help of the enumitem package.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}

\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{2} % just for this example

A displayed and numbered equation:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:a}
1+1=2
\end{equation}
and a cross-reference to \cref{eq:a}.

An enumerated list that's ``numbered'' the same way as a displayed equation:  
\begin{enumerate}[format=\refstepcounter{equation}, label=(\theequation), left=0pt]
\item  First enumerated fact.  \label{item:I}
\item  Second enumerated fact. 
\end{enumerate} 
I want to cross-reference \cref{item:I} the same way as \cref{eq:a}.
\end{document}


The trouble is: The enumerated items are "numbered" (labeled?) correctly, but they are not cross-referenced correctly. BTW, this isn't a cleveref issue -- the same issue arises with \ref and \eqref.
Question: What am I missing? Note that it's important that I use the enumitem package.

\begin{enumerate}[before={\crefalias{enumi}{equation}},.... should probably work.

@UlrikeFischer - Thanks for this suggestion. This'll affect the label generated by \cref{item:I} ("equation" instead of the default "item"), but it doesn't appear to fix the incorrect-number issue (which should be "2.2" but is still "2.1").

I think I get the why. When you do format=\refstepcounter{equation} this is done within a group restricted to the label of the item. Though \refstepcounter changes to the counter itself are global, the settings of \@currentlabel and \@currentcounter are local. Hence not visible by \label{item:I}.

first*=\def\@listctr{equation} seems to get the job done (and something equivalent is the only way I can see to do it with enumitem's options).

@gusbrs - Thanks. May I ask you to be a bit more specific? (If I insert first*=\def\@listctr{equation} into the list of options of \begin{enumerate}, the output of \cref{item:I} is unchanged from I showed in the screenshot.)

@Mico I've tested, and it works here (you need \makeatletter, of course, for that incantation). You could use \usecounter{equation}, but since that resets the counter, you'd need to restore it...

@gusbrs - Please go ahead and post an answer; I'll gladly upvote. :-)

@Mico If it solves it, feel free to self-answer. It's a little late here, I just tried things out because the question got me curious.  ;-)

@gusbrs - There's no rush. :-)

I'd define a special environment.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}

% define a proper environment
\newlist{eqlist}{enumerate}{1}
\crefname{eqlisti}{item}{items}
% the counter is shared
\ExpandArgs{cc}\RenewCommandCopy{c@eqlisti}{c@equation}
\setlist[eqlist,1]{
  left=0pt,                      % labels flush left
  label=\textup{(\theequation)}, % like for equations
  before=\stepcounter{equation}, % we want to go on with numbering
  resume,                        % don't forget the final number
}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{2} % just for this example

A displayed and numbered equation:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:a}
1+1=2
\end{equation}
and a cross-reference to \cref{eq:a}.

An enumerated list that's ``numbered'' the same way as a displayed equation:  
\begin{eqlist}
\item  First enumerated fact.  \label{item:I}
\item  Second enumerated fact. 
\end{eqlist} 
I want to cross-reference \cref{item:I} the same way as \cref{eq:a}.

A displayed and numbered equation:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:b}
1+1=2
\end{equation}
and a cross-reference to \cref{eq:b}.

An enumerated list that's ``numbered'' the same way as a displayed equation:  
\begin{eqlist}
\item  First enumerated fact.  \label{item:I+}
\item  Second enumerated fact. 
\end{eqlist} 
I want to cross-reference \cref{item:I+} the same way as \cref{eq:b}.

\end{document}



+1. :-) Would you know why changing before=\stepcounter{equation} to before=\refstepcounter{equation} ends up inserting a lot of extra vertical whitespace at the start of an eqlist environment?

@Mico First off, you don't want \refstepcounter, because you don't need to set a label. Besides, with \refstepcounter you get an anchor from hyperref, which is the cause of the space.

Many thanks for this explanation.

@Mico Because it's a comment on his answer so I'm asking him already. And you seemed to understand the explanation, so I was really asking both/either? Apologies if you feel unjustly targeted.

@egreg Why doesn't Mico need a label?

@Mico ^^ Not addressed to you at all ;).

@cfr The \stepcounter is a “technical” need; labels go after \item

Thanks. I don't think I understand that, but I probably asked the wrong question.

@cfr There are two counters at play here. \refstepcounter is called, but on eqlisti (by \item, and that's why the "type" of the reference is "item"). The equation counter just needs to be kept in sync with eqlisti, thus \stepcounter is not only sufficient for equation but calling \refstepcounter on it would do the wrong thing.

@gusbrs But there's only one underlying count isn't there? If you need to keep equation in sync with eqlisti, why don't you need to do that for every \item?

@cfr You're right. I need the manual to navigate enumitem's options and somehow took before as "once per item", which is not correct. I have to think about this one again later (out of curiosity ;-), but won't be able to today...

When you do format=\refstepcounter{equation}, \refstepcounter is called within \makelabel, which is grouped. The counter itself is, of course, stepped globally, but the the variables which are supposed to be available to the next \label -- \@currentlabel and \@currentcounter -- are lost when the group ends, thus \label{item:I} does not see those values as set by \refstepcounter{equation}.
Now, calling \refstepcounter{equation} after \item (somehow) is too late, because the item's label is already typeset and calling it before \item is too early because it will be overwritten by the internal \refstepcounter of  \item. The only place you could do this is somewhere between the internal \refstepcounter called by \item and \makelabel. I see no place at all in enumitem's code where this could be done, short of hacking your way through.
But, it is simple enough to make enumerate use equation as it's counter.  Since we don't want to reset it, we cannot use directly \usecounter, but we can only set \@listctr to be equation instead.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}

\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mysetlistctr}[1]{\def\@listctr{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{2} % just for this example

A displayed and numbered equation:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:a}
1+1=2
\end{equation}
and a cross-reference to \cref{eq:a}.

An enumerated list that's ``numbered'' the same way as a displayed equation:
\begin{enumerate}[first*=\mysetlistctr{equation}, label=(\theequation), left=0pt]
\item  First enumerated fact.  \label{item:I}
\item  Second enumerated fact.
\end{enumerate}
I want to cross-reference \cref{item:I} the same way as \cref{eq:a}.
\end{document}


No need to tamper with \crefalias, or similar, since cleveref will just "believe" this is a normal equation.
Of course, this is a little devious, and you need to exert some self-restraint in using it (e.g. nesting will not turn out pretty, etc.). But, otherwise, seems to get the job done in a reasonable way.

I like the generality of your approach. E.g., if I wanted to change the word label that's used in a cross-reference to an enumerated item from "equation" to "item", all I'd need to do is change \label{item:I} to \label[enumi]{item:I}, as cleveref already "knows" which word label (viz., "item") to use for objects associated with the enumi object type. If this weren't already set up, a suitable \crefalias instruction along with a \crefname instruction would accomplish the supplemental labelling job.
